# How to include files generated by a custom MSBuild task to the Solution Explorer and Intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/msbuild/tutorial-custom-task-code-generation.md) to create a MSBuild task that produces a generated C# file from another document.

The relevant integration code from that tutorial which integrates the task into a MSBuild project is this (the name of the example custom task is AppSettingStronglyTyped) :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <UsingTask TaskName="AppSettingStronglyTyped.AppSettingStronglyTyped" AssemblyFile="..\..\AppSettingStronglyTyped\AppSettingStronglyTyped\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppSettingStronglyTyped.dll"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</RootFolder>
        <SettingClass>MySetting</SettingClass>
        <SettingNamespace>MSBuildConsoleExample</SettingNamespace>
        <SettingExtensionFile>mysettings</SettingExtensionFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <SettingFiles Include="$(RootFolder)\*.mysettings" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="GenerateSetting" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" Inputs="@(SettingFiles)" Outputs="$(RootFolder)\$(SettingClass).generated.cs">
        <AppSettingStronglyTyped SettingClassName="$(SettingClass)" SettingNamespaceName="$(SettingNamespace)" SettingFiles="@(SettingFiles)">
        <Output TaskParameter="ClassNameFile" PropertyName="SettingClassFileName" />
        </AppSettingStronglyTyped>
        <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Remove="$(SettingClassFileName)" />
            <Compile Include="$(SettingClassFileName)" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="ForceReGenerateOnRebuild" AfterTargets="CoreClean">
        <Delete Files="$(RootFolder)\$(SettingClass).generated.cs" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

My own task is properly run during the build process, and the code compiles as expected.

My problem is that the generated file does not appear in the Visual Studio solution explorer. It is also not considered for autocompletion or code analysis by Intellisense, which makes it produce false positive errors before I build, and underline my generated types in red, etc.

I guess that I could come up with some hacks around this (using a conditional Compile element at the project root in cas my file is alread generated, etc.) but I think there must be a non-hacky solution around that problem. Maybe I'm not inserting my task at the proper location in the build process? How would you advise to integrate the generated code with VS in a better way, please?